# Can not pass flake8p test

Tags: python, unit-testing, makefile, pytest, flake8

I have Makefile and command inside it:

```
.PHONY: lint
lint:
    poetry run flake8p
```

I get following error:

```
There was a critical error during execution of Flake8:
plugin code for `flake8-mock[flake8_mock]` does not match ^[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{0,3}$
make: *** [lint] Error 1
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score -1):

It bug related to https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/barman/issues/635

I should

Freeze flake8 version to 4.0.1 until 5.x.x fixes issues (closes #635)

Comment: flake8 5.x.x is never going to "fix this" -- the bug is in `flake8-mock`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).